# Show a single div a time on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code I want this show only div I as the first view someone sees
not to show all the content. When I remove all the button div one shows all the content

```js
$('#showall').click(function(){
    $('all').show();
});

$('#showdiv1').click(function(){
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div1').show();
});
$('#showdiv2').click(function(){
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div2').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="buttons">
    <a class="button" id="showall">All</a>
    <a class="button" id="showdiv1">Div 1</a>
    <a class="button" id="showdiv2">Div 2</a>          
</div>
<div id="all">1</div>
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
```

Comment: I'm not following you, description is confuse. What is your problem? It seems that you're missing `#` in `$('all')`... but I guess this is not the whole issue at all.

Comment: i dont want want the divs to show all

Comment: when i remove showall the div content shows on button 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.all').hide(); //hide div 1 & 2 at the beginning
$('#all').hide(); //hide all at the beginning
$('#showall').click(function(){
    $('.all').hide();
    $('#all').show();
});
$('#show1').click(function(){
    $('.all').hide();
    $('#all').hide();
    $('#div1').show();
});
$('#show2').click(function(){
    $('.all').hide();
    $('#all').hide();
    $('#div2').show();
});
$('#showdiv1').click(function(){
    $('.all').hide();
    $('#all').show();
    $('#div1').show();
});
$('#showdiv2').click(function(){
    $('.all').hide();
    $('#all').show();
    $('#div2').show();
});
$('#showdiv12').click(function(){
    $('#all').hide();
    $('.all').show();
});
$('#showeverything').click(function(){
    $('#all').show();
    $('.all').show();
});
$('#removediv').click(function(){
    $('.all').hide();
});
$('#removeall').click(function(){
    $('#all').hide();
    $('.all').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" id="showall">Show 1(All) Only</button>
<button class="button" id="show1">Show Div 1 Only</button>
<button class="button" id="show2">Show Div 2 Only</button>
<button class="button" id="showdiv1">Show 1(All) and Div 1</button>
<button class="button" id="showdiv2">Show 1(All) and Div 2</button>
<button class="button" id="showdiv12">Show Div 1 and 2 Only</button>
<button class="button" id="showeverything">Show Everything</button>
<button class="button" id="removediv">Hide Div 1 and 2</button>
<button class="button" id="removeall">Hide Everything</button>
<div id="all">1 (All)</div>
<div id="div1" class="all">1 (Div 1)</div>
<div id="div2" class="all">1 (Div 2)</div>
```

Comment: i dont want the showall button to show all content i want the first content to be 1

Comment: Please describe what you want each button to do. I updated the answer hope its the one you want

Comment: Updated the answer with every possible show/hide situation buttons you might need. just use the ones you think you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get()` and avoid have unique `id` for individual `div`.

```js
$('.buttons a').click(function() {
  let showId = $(this).attr('show');
  $('.container div').hide(); // hide all
  $($('.container div').get(showId)).show();
});
```

```css
.container div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="buttons">
  <a show='0'>All</a>
  <a show='1'>Div 1</a>
  <a show='2'>Div 2</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>All</div>
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
</div>
```